# Not Finding nearest Places

Tags: android

I need to develop an application using Google Maps in Android to locate my current location and need to find nearest mosjid. 
i'm getting current location if i click find button nothing happening.. It not show nearby places

```
package com.soft.mapexample;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements     
LocationListener{                                                                                                                                                                                 

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;   
Spinner mSprPlaceType;  

String[] mPlaceType=null;
String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;

double mLatitude=0;
double mLongitude=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    // Array of place types
    mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

    // Array of place type names
    mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

    // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
    // to populate the spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   
   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);

    // Getting reference to the Spinner 
    mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

    // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
    mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button btnFind;

    // Getting reference to Find Button
    btnFind = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);


    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = 
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());


    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not 
  available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 
  requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
        SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) 
   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Google Map
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service 
 LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
  getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location From GPS
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

        // Setting click event lister for the find button
        btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   


            int selectedPosition =                                   
                                   mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder
 ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                sb.append("&radius=5000");
                sb.append("&types="+type);
                sb.append("&sensor=true");
                sb.append("&key=API_KEY");


    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
                PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();                                   

    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                placesTask.execute(sb.toString());


            }
        });

    }       

}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);                


            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();                

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new    
InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return data;
}         


/** A class, to download Google Places */
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    String data = null;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
             Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }

}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, 
List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... 
jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;            
        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){            

        // Clears all the existing markers 
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));                

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker. 
            //This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);               

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);            

        }       

    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

PlaceJSONParser.Java

```
package com.soft.mapexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PlaceJSONParser {

/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

    JSONArray jPlaces = null;
    try {           
        /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
        jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
     * where each json object represent a place
     */
    return getPlaces(jPlaces);
}


private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces){
    int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new 
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> place = null;   

    /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
    for(int i=0; i<placesCount;i++){
        try {
            /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
            place = getPlace((JSONObject)jPlaces.get(i));
            placesList.add(place);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return placesList;
}

/** Parsing the Place JSON object */
private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace){

    HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String placeName = "-NA-";
    String vicinity="-NA-";
    String latitude="";
    String longitude="";


    try {
        // Extracting Place name, if available
        if(!jPlace.isNull("name")){
            placeName = jPlace.getString("name");
        }

        // Extracting Place Vicinity, if available
        if(!jPlace.isNull("vicinity")){
            vicinity = jPlace.getString("vicinity");
        }   

        latitude = 
jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
        longitude = 
jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");            


        place.put("place_name", placeName);
        place.put("vicinity", vicinity);
        place.put("lat", latitude);
        place.put("lng", longitude);


    } catch (JSONException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return place;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spr_place_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_find"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"        
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spr_place_type"
    android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />    

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/spr_place_type"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

String.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">LocationNearby</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="str_btn_find">Find</string>

<string-array name="place_type">
    <item>airport</item>
    <item>atm</item>
    <item>bank</item>
    <item>bus_station</item>        
    <item>church</item>
    <item>doctor</item>
    <item>hospital</item>        
    <item>mosque</item>
    <item>movie_theater</item>
    <item>hindu_temple</item>
    <item>restaurant</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="place_type_name">
    <item>Airport</item>
    <item>ATM</item>
    <item>Bank</item>
    <item>Bus Station</item>
    <item>Church</item>
    <item>Doctor</item>
    <item>Hospital</item>
    <item>Mosque</item>
    <item>Movie Theater</item>
    <item>Hindu Temple</item>
    <item>Restaurant</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gasoft.mapexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission
    android:name="com.soft.mapexample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission   
android:name="com.soft.mapexample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>    

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.soft.mapexample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

            <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="api_key"/>        

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a API_KEY and use that in your application.

instead of `sb.append("&key=API_KEY")`

use `sb.append("&key="+CREATED_API_KEY)`

Comment: Did you followed google doc and created your API_KEY ?
And again try to print your json data in logcat. There may be possibility that there is no Masjid available in 5km radius from your place

Comment: that thing also me tried.. around me there is 10 masjid available

Comment: So what's your actual problem? You are not getting json response or not able to show in map

Comment: just confirm your place `type` and print `type` in logcat before putting that in url and also print `jPlaces` in logcat before
`return getPlaces(jPlaces);`